# ChunkLoadError when Adding a custom domain to my site

Tags: github, dns, netlify, hugo

In Netlify, when I am trying to add a custom domain to my site in Domain management. I have the following error:

```
ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk 9929 failed. (error: Netlify App)
```

I am using Hugo and GitHub.
Do you know how to solve this issue ?

Comment: Hey mate, you're not going to get a good answer unfortunately as this is just debugging which would require access to your repos and netlify config. 
There's a lot of reasons why loading could fail, and not really tied to Hugo or Github (per se) I would suggest checking answers.netlify.com and then if a specific question, I think you'll get more responses.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.